# Why do I get the error: "No command 'update' found"?

Tags: command-line, updates

I just have installed Ubuntu 10.10 , but when I enter `update` in the terminal I get this message :

```
No command 'update' found, did you mean:
 Command 'uupdate' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'lupdate' from package 'libqt4-dev' (main)
 Command 'lupdate' from package 'qt3-dev-tools' (main)
update: command not found
```

Would you please help me if you have any idea?

Comment: 10.10 has reached end of life and is no longer supported.  You should install 12.04 instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`update` is not a command. `apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages. `update` is an option to this command.

It is used to **synchronize package index files from their sources via the internet**.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To apply these updates, run it with the option `upgrade`

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This **installs the newest versions of all packages currently installed on your system.**

Additionally, if you want to get updates and apply them by just one command `update`, you could add the following line in your `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias update='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'
```

Comment: Besides, you should really consider moving away from 10.10 as it has reached its end-of-life status.